# Reference for some pencils of plane curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-curves

Recently I came across the following pencils of (complex projective) plane curves:
$$
\{x^{3n}+y^{3n}+z^{3n} + tx^ny^nz^n=0\mid t\in \mathbb{P}^1\}
$$
and
$$
\{(x^{n}+y^{n}+z^{n})^3 + tx^ny^nz^n=0\mid t\in \mathbb{P}^1\}
$$
for a natural number $n$.

Are these pencils well-known in literature? I could not find any reference besides Harui's paper [Automorphism groups of smooth plane curves](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1306.5842.pdf).